# Passing parameters for class

Tags: java

How Can i pass these parameters to a class HelloClass from main method that include the following parameters :

HelloClass 4d.txt 1000 9 0.6 [ this is from command line ]

Where HelloClass is a class name
4d.txt is file name 
1000 is an int parameters value 
9 is an int parameters value 
0.6 is a float parameter value

Where is should call it in the form

a class main method is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HelloClass start = new HelloClass(args);

}
```

and the args array should be {4d.txt,1000,9,0.6} now, how can i pass this args to a class HelloClass Constructor at once time , not from command line console

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: Are you having a specific problem? Looks to me like you're pretty much there... Just make a constructor to accept the parameters you want, and then pass them in.

Comment: Not sure if you are talking about passing parameters to an object of a class (constructor) or you want command-line arguments.

Comment: the class consists of a constructor like this public HelloClass (String [] args ) and the args is a parameters from main method but include many types such as string, int and float and i need to pass at once time to such constructor

Comment: Have a constructor in HelloClass which accepts this parameters..

Comment: @mumenh if you want to post additional code, try editing your question.  I will also help if you format the code (check the formatting help while editing)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
public class HelloClass {

    /**
     * be sure to handle errors and exceptions
     *
     */
    public HelloClass(String[] params) {
        if (params.length == 4) {
            String paramOne = params[0];
            int paramTwo = Integer.parseInt(params[1]);
            int paramThree = Integer.parseInt(params[2]);
            float paramFour = Float.parseFloat(params[3]);

           //Now do something with those parameters;
        }
    }
}
```

Now to call it within a main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //If you are getting your arguments from Command line
    HelloClass myHelloClassWithCommandArguments = new HelloClass(args);

    //If you are passing pre-defined arguments or such.
    HelloClass myHelloClassWithCustomArguments = new HelloClass(new String[]{"d4.txt", "1000", "9", "0.6"});
}
```

Comment: Thank you gtgaxiola , i got it